# Как составить MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть простая задача. Структура базы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача:
для всех дилерских центров те модели (mark.name), для которых суммарное количество выставленных на продажу экземпляров больше 10 (stock.quantity). В этом же запросе для каждой модели указать центр (shop.name), в котором находится наибольшее количество моделей (если таких несколько, то отсортировать по имени центра в алфавитном порядке).

Выбрать суммы несложно:

```
SELECT mark.name AS MARK, (SUM(stock.quantity)) AS TOTAL, shop.name
FROM mark
JOIN stock ON stock.markID = mark.id
GROUP BY mark.name HAVING SUM(stock.quantity) > 10
```

Но как добавить дилерские центры?

Comment: _как добавить дилерские центры?_ В запросе уже есть join - вот, как-то так и добавляйте

Comment: Знал бы как, наверное, не спрашивал

Answer (score 1):

Довольно интересная задача ! Предлагаю разбить её на шаги

1. Выбрать shopid, markid, MAX(quantity) as MQ
2. Выбрать из запроса (1) markid, MAX(MQ)
3. Соединить запросы (1) и (2) по markid, MAX(MQ)
4. Результат отсортировать

Comment: А как их соединить? Я получаю 2 таблицы с mark.id но через UNION они объединятся в одну с дублированием записей mark.id. Как сделать соединить запросы чтобы в итоге была 1 таблица с 3 столбцами?

Comment: На первый взгляд вопрос кажется странным (как соединить), но мне кажется я понимаю о чём речь ... Общий принцип такой SELECT t1.Поле, t2.поле FROM (_t1) AS t1 LEFT JOIN (_t2) AS t2 ON t1.поле = t2.Поле ; тут _t1 и _t2 запросы получающие таблицы

Comment: Ответ правильный, только MQ не MAX(quantity), а SUM(quantity)

Answer (score 1):

```
       SELECT mark.name AS MARK, (SUM(stock.quantity)) AS TOTAL, shop.name as SHOP   
FROM mark
JOIN stock ON stock.markID = mark.id
JOIN shop ON stock.shopID = shop.id
GROUP BY mark.name HAVING SUM(stock.quantity) > 10
union 
SELECT mark.name AS mark, (SUM(stock.quantity)) AS TOTAL, shop.name AS shop
FROM shop 
JOIN stock ON stock.shopid = shop.id 
JOIN mark ON mark.id=stock.markid 
GROUP BY mark.name HAVING max(stock.quantity) AND SUM(stock.quantity) > 10
```